# How to get the currently active tf.variable_scope in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, named-scope

I wrote a convenience API to define my models in TensorFlow that exposes a scope object. Now I want to verify that the user actually enters the scope before adding operations. How to get the name of the currently active tf.variable_scope in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use tf.get_variable_scope() to get the currently active scope:

```
using tensorflow as tf
with tf.variable_scope("my_scope"):
  print(tf.get_variable_scope().name)
```

This will print "my_scope"